# Why aren't these two result sets adding up?

Tags: mysql, left-join, distinct

I have a "master" table (`cited_papers`) of 144,194 rows, and a "sample" table (`publication`) that contains a sample of 7,977 of these rows.  I am trying to get the rows (by their unique `id` field) that are in the master table but not the sample table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM alex_WOS.cited_papers as c LEFT JOIN alex_WOS.publication USING (id)
WHERE alex_WOS.publication.id IS NULL
```

This works, but the result count I get is 141,019.  Why aren't these counts adding up?  (141,019 + 7977 != 144,194) I did a `SELECT DISTINCT` to count the rows in both the master and sample tables, so I am certain there are no duplicates in either of those tables.

Comment: Is there anything in `publications` that isn't in `cited_papers`. Perhaps reverse that query above just as a sanity check.

Comment: "Left join x where x " equals "inner join x"

Comment: Are there duplicated IDs (not duplicated rows) in the tables? Try select count(distinct id) from alex_WOS.cited_papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinct may be throwing things off. Run the queries below to verify your numbers.

Verify the number of "master" rows:
`SELECT count(*) FROM alex_WOS.cited_papers`

Verify the number of "sample" rows:
`SELECT count(*) FROM alex_WOS.publication`

Verify the number of "master" rows not in "sample" table:
`SELECT count(*) FROM alex_WOS.cited_papers c LEFT JOIN alex_WOS.publication p USING(id) WHERE p.id IS NULL`

These numbers should add up...

Comment: 144194, 7977, and 141019.  I think JNevill might actually be on to something, and perhaps my "sample" isn't actually a subset after all.  If only this damn server would stop timing out on me...

Answer (score 0):

As JNevill suggested, my `sample` table was not a subset of `master` after all.  I'm a dummy...